# Scrapy Shell XPath

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-shell

I am trying to get links and category from this http://www.npr.org/rss/#feeds news feed website.

This is my xpath  in scrapy shell:

```
a = sel.xpath('//ul[@class="rsslinks"]/li/a/@href').extract()

b = sel.xpath('//ul[@class="rsslinks"]/li/a/text()').extract()
```

But length of b is one lesser than length of a. I don't know what I am missing here. But this is causing problems in data.

From the image below,the category name is "Most Emailed Stories" but link is for "News Headlines"

Any help would be appreciated[image: Xpath Screen]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of the first link in the results:

```
<a class="iconlink xml" href="/rss/rss.php?id=1001" target="blank"><strong>News Headlines</strong></a>
```

As you can see, there is no direct child "text" nodes, only one `strong` element. Your xpath would not match it.

Add an another slash to get all text nodes from the `a` tag:

```
//ul[@class="rsslinks"]/li/a//text()
                         HERE^
```

Comment: In my opinion, the wording of your answer is misleading because it suggests that there is a `text` element in the sense of an element node named "text", in the same way as `strong.` Please make it clear that text nodes are not element nodes.

Comment: @MathiasMüller very good point, thanks, I think it should be better now. And, btw, thanks for contributing to `xpath` tag - learning a lot from your answers.

Comment: + 1, it's fine now. And dito, I can only return the compliment!

Answer (score 1):

The text for /rss/rss.php?id=1001 with the label of News Headlines appears to be another level down under `<strong> </strong>`while the other links are not.

Comment: Yes,my bad ! Didn't notice that,thanks for the help !